# Ubuntu wireless not woking

Tags: wireless, 15.10, hp

I'm new to ubuntu and i have an **HP Presario CQ57 (32-bit)** running **Ubuntu 15.10** but the wi-ifi doesn't seem to work. I figured it might be a driver problem because when i plug the Ethernet cable everything's fine. My wireless card is **Raling RT5390 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe**. Any help is welcome...

Answer (score 0):

I have read of many people who have this problem. It would seem a kernel bug. What you can do is either install an older version of the kernel without this problem (linux version 3.19) or try if it works with a live Ubuntu 14.04 and in case of a positive result keep Ubuntu 14.04